# Sequelize - Count Based on Include Condition

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using the `sequelize` `count` function as follows:

Definition:

```
const countAllOrdersWhere = async (conditions) =>
    Order.count({
        where: conditions,
    })
        .then((count) => ({ count, error: null }))
        .catch((error) => ({ count: null, error }));
```

Usage:

```
  const { count, error: countError } = await countAllOrdersWhere({
                    [Op.or]: [
                        { userId: userIds, status },
                        { status, venueId },
                    ],
                });
```

This works great, however I now need to add a condition based on an associated model:

1. Each `order` has many `orderItems` associated with it (there's an `orderId` on each row in the `orderItem` table.)
2. Each `orderItem` has one `item` associated with it - (there's an `itemid` on each row in the `orderItem` table.)

I have an array of `itemIds` and I would like to only count the orders which are associated with an `orderItem` which has an `itemId` which is in my list.

When querying the `orders`, I enforce this clause in a `findAll` function by doing

```
include: [
 {
 model: OrderItem,   
 where: Sequelize.literal(
      itemIds && itemIds.length > 0
      ? `"orderItems"."itemId" IN (${itemIds})`
      : 'true'
 )}]
```

however, I'm not sure how to do this in a `count` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `count` method also has `include` option so you can use it the ame way as you did with `findAll`, see [count](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-count)

```js
const countAllOrdersWhere = async (conditions) =>
    Order.count({
        include: [
 {
   model: OrderItem,   
   // this option is important in order to get the correct result (leads to INNER JOIN
  // instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN)
   required: true,
   where: (itemIds && itemIds.length > 0) ? {
     itemId: {
      [Op.in]: itemIds
     }
   } : {}
  }]
  }).then((count) => ({ count, error: null }))
    .catch((error) => ({ count: null, error }));
```